# Get XPath of parent

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

here's code:

```
<div class="x-form-item " tabindex="-1" role="presentation">
    <label class="x-form-item-label" style="width:180px;" for="x-auto-4005-input">Amount split option:</label>
    <div id="x-form-el-x-auto-4005" class="x-form-element x-form-el-x-auto-4005" style="padding-left:185px" role="presentation">
        <div id="x-auto-4005" class=" x-form-field-wrap x-component x-trigger-wrap-focus" role="combobox" style="width: 240px;">
```

I would like to access element with id "x-auto-4005", but without using this id. I can see that label element has identifier "Amount split option". How can I access my element using the label? I guess I would have to get XPATH of parent of all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following xpath:

```
"//label[text()='Amount split option:']/following::div[2]"
```

Comment: Could You tell me what will it locate? this '2' index is for 2nd parent, or 2nd div (class=x-form-item) child, wchich is div (id="x-form-el-x-auto-4005"?

Comment: It will locate `<div id="x-auto-4005" class=" x-form-field-wrap x-component x-trigger-wrap-focus" role="combobox" style="width: 240px;">`. It will take the second `div` element after the `label` element.

Comment: Thank You very much. What if I would like to locate parent of the parent (hipothetically)? Because i believe /following::following/ won't work

Comment: @sajczix - Well, you can write something like this: `"//label[text()='Amount split option:']//following::div//following::div"`. It will locate the same div which you've asked for.

Comment: I wanted to rate answer but I have no permission. Already accepted. Thank You :)